# Changing the theme for default windows in Awesome WM

Tags: awesome

How can I change the theme for default windows in Awesome WM?

By default windows I mean the window that pops out when you open the preference window in gnome terminal, or pop out the noscript add-on in Firefox. Windows that theme wasn't specified otherwise basically.

Comment: Basically this question was answered at Askubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/100411/how-do-i-apply-themes-to-gtk-applications-when-im-using-awesome-wm

Answer (score 0):

You can change the theme by changing the file loaded in rc.lua.
In Awesome 4.0 you can change the line beautiful.init(/path/to/theme.lua)